# What is the equivalent command of "minikube start --memory 5120 --cpus=4" for "Kind"?

Tags: memory, cassandra, cpu, kubernetes-service, kind

Here in [Cassandra deployment instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/), it says:

> Caution:
>
> Minikube defaults to 2048MB of memory and 2 CPU. Running Minikube with
> the default resource configuration results in insufficient resource
> errors during this tutorial. To avoid these errors, start Minikube
> with the following settings:
>
> minikube start --memory 5120 --cpus=4

But I don't know what is the equivalent command if I use `Kind` instead of `minikube`?

I also like to know if I want to set these settings permanently for my `Kind` cluster, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kind does not work like minikube, it inherit the resources from the host. If you want to limit the resources then create an vm with specified limit and create kind cluster in it. You can check similar discussion on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1422) thread